# How to open new HTML tab after clicking on the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the landing page with some buttons to function.

[image]

When I click the `Send Money` button, it opens the `sendMoney.html` in the same tab. The code is following,

```
$("#sendMoney").click(function () {
    var address = $('#address').find(":selected").text();
    location.href = 'sendMoney.html#' + address;

});
```

How to open the `sendMoney.html` in the new tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you require you can use `window.open()`. Although the name suggest it'll open a popup window, the request will actually be redirected to a new tab in all modern browsers. Try this:

```
$("#sendMoney").click(function () {
    var address = $('#address').find(":selected").text();
    window.open('sendMoney.html#' + address);
});
```

Comment: Use `_blank` to open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#sendMoney").click(function () {
    var address = $('#address').find(":selected").text();
    window.open('sendMoney.html#' + address);
});
```

Instead of using window.location, use `window.open("your link");`. With `window.location` its not possible to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<a> button text here <a/>` to make a button and use attribute target as _blank to open page in new tab

Or

you can use window.open() function as

```
window.open(URL, name,)
```

Value for name can be

- blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
- _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
- _self - URL replaces the current page
- _top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded name - The name of the window (Note: the name does not specify the title of the new
  window)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry dear but try to read slowly , there is a "or" between anchor tag portion and window.open portion

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `window.open()` which will open new tab in most of the new browsers. Here is the updated code:

```
$("#sendMoney").click(function () {
    var address = $('#address option:selected').text();
    window.open('sendMoney.html#' + address);
});
```